# Como pegar as coordenadas/posição do cursor do mouse, em javascript?

Tags: javascript

De preferência sem uso de frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode capturar isso com um event listener:

`document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var posX = event.clientX,
      posY = event.clientY;
});`

Comment: Obrigado, Luan!

Comment: Por nada! Fico feliz em ter ajudado.